# DebugDiag throws NullReferenceException when reading dump file

Tags: .net, debugging, debugdiag

When I attempt to do a performance analysis on a dump file with DebugDiag 2.1, I get a NullReferenceException with the following stack trace in the report:

```
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.CDumps.DoVersionsMatch(String& v1, String& v2)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.CDumps.SomeDotNetImageFilesAreMissingOrMismatched(NetDbgObj debugger)
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.CDumps.SaveModulesAndAppendExePaths()
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfAnalysis.VerifyAndSortDumps()
DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.PerfAnalysis.RunAnalysisRule(NetScriptManager manager, NetProgress progress)
```

The application being analysed is running .Net 4.5.2.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Is it outdated? Because I didn't get anything useful from this tool.